# Software to run photo booth

Tags: photography

I am currently in the process of creating a photo booth which will be used at a wedding.

The booth is the traditional box shape, with a red curtain. Something similar to this.
[image: Photo booth with red curtain]

People need to be able to enter the booth, take photos, and then either have them printed then or request prints later.

the hardware I currently have is:

- PC (Currently has windows installed)
- Camera
- Monitor (touch screen)
- Android tablet
- Printer
- Many peripherals such as; Speakers, keyboards, mice, etc..

Is there any free software or operating systems which I can use to make the experience as authentic as possible?

The basic requirements are

- Simple to use (Elderly/non-tech savvy users)
- Able to store all photos taken so I can print later or supply digital images

Extra features that would be nice:

- Share to social media
- Get the image emailed to yourself
- Print after taking the photo

If more information is required, please, let me know.

Comment: Please describe more specifically about what you need. Most everyone has a phone in their pocket that can take photos and store all images taken.

Comment: @BasilBourque thanks for the comment, I have now updated the question. Just as a note, there are a lot of older people who don't have/know how to use smart phones.

Answer (score 1):

I had previously tried OpenPhotoBooth, but wasn't satisfied with the lack of features or rate of development. It only works on XP with Canon Powershot cameras, and was last updatedin 2015.

It looks like there is something called FreeBooth, but the download links on the website all point to 192.168.x.x, and the contact form doesn't work. Will the authors ever notice that nobody can download their product?

**Edit (2017.06.17):** After a little bit of poking around, I found that the download link should point to https://sourceforge.net/projects/freebooth/files/latest/download but the website still hasn't been updated to reflect this.